# Responsive bootstrap menu, socicons, phone number and mail id not showing in mobile

Tags: css

this is my site and when viewed in mobile the bootstrap menu, socicons and the phone number & mail id are not showing in mobile. In desktop it is ok. pls help

http://www.contentngraphicdesigns.in/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Have you tried to check responsiveness using builtin browser tools ?

Comment: @Paulie_D is correct, but quickly looking at your page I see a huge amount of 404 replies from the server (just check the network tab in the developer console). Double check the required files / libraries / images are deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace a small piece of code in your css/layout.min.css file here:

```
body, html, html a {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-size: 18px;
width: auto;
/* white-space: nowrap; */
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```